# Swift 3: Getting error while joining the reversed() array

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I have code like this:

```
    class Stack<T>: CustomStringConvertible {

    fileprivate var array: [T] = []

    func pop() -> T? {
        let popItem = self.array.popLast()
        print("POP ITEM : \(popItem)")
        return popItem
    }

    func push(item: T) {
        print("PUSH ITEM : \(item)")
        array.append(item)
    }

    var isEmpty: Bool {
        return self.array.isEmpty
    }

    var count: Int {
        return self.array.count
    }

    var description: String {
        let topDivider = "### STACK ###\n"
        let bottomDivider = "\n############\n"
        let stackElements = self.array.reversed().joined(separator: "\n") // GETTING ERROR
        return topDivider + stackElements + bottomDivider
    }

}
```

> Error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

I'm unable to join that reverse array.

REF : https://www.raywenderlich.com/149213/swift-algorithm-club-swift-stack-data-structure

Here they have done in struct with String successfully.

Can i know How i can achieve same here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `joined` function requires that the separator be the same data type as the values being joined. Since `self.array` is an array of `T`, you can't pass a `String` as the separator. This mismatch is causing the error.

Since this is your `description` property and your goal is to get a string representation of the array, one solution would be to map the array of `T` to an array of `String`. Then you can join that `String` array with your newline separator.

One way to convert something to a `String` is to call the `description` method on it. But to do that, you need to limit your `T` to only those types that provide the `description` method which comes from `CustomStringConvertible`.

Change your class declaration to:

```
class Stack<T:CustomStringConvertible>: CustomStringConvertible {
```

and then your `description` property to:

```
var description: String {
    let topDivider = "### STACK ###\n"
    let bottomDivider = "\n############\n"
    let stackElements = self.array.reversed().map { $0.description }.joined(separator: "\n")
    return topDivider + stackElements + bottomDivider
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Map your generic type `T` to `String` and then apply `joined()` function.

`joined` is only for elements of type `String` and here compiler do not know the type of `T`.

```
let stackElements = self.array.map{"\($0)"}.reversed().joined(separator: "\n")
```